# Movie Sales by Genre dimensional modeling

Tags: ssas, olap, dimensional-modeling

Let's say I want to find out movie sales per year by genre in an OLAP cube. The data structure would look like this:

```
{
    "Year": 2020,
    "Title": "Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse",
    "Revenue": 102000,
    "Genres": ["Action", "Sci-Fi"]
}
```

What would be the proper way to model this? Would I un-nest the genres so that the genre itself is multiplied by the sales? For example, the fact table would look like:

```
+------------+
| Movie Fact |
+------------+
| Year       |
| Title      |     (1 record for the above data)
| Revenue    |
+------------+
```

Or would it look like:

```
+------------+
| Movie Fact |
+------------+
| Year       |
| Title      |     (TWO records for the above data)
| Revenue    |
| Genre      |
+------------+
```

Why would it be one way over the other?

Comment: What are your business rules for handling/allocating revenue when a movie is associated to multiple genres?

Comment: @NickW in the above case, we would double count. That is, if we grouped by Genre, both Action and Sci-Fi should show 102000 revenue.

Comment: In which case add Genre as a dimension to your fact table. However (and obviously I don't know your business/requirements), double counting is almost always the wrong design, IMO

Comment: @NickW in the above scenario, what is the more common approach then? For example, what if we wanted to add in "cast and crew" to a movie? How could we see which actor had the highest gross?

Comment: In a scenario where you have multiple dimension records per fact record then you have to use a bridge table. If measures can be allocated between these many dimension records (which is probably not the case with what you are modelling) then you can include a "factor" value in the bridge table

Comment: I'll probably revise my statement about a design that allows double counting to probably be wrong. If you don't care about double counting then it's fine - where you may get into trouble is if different queries against the same star need to treat double counting differently. Users may be used to writing queries against it where double counting is not an issue but then write a query where it is an issue - and not realise that they need to allow for it. If this is a genuine risk then I'd be tempted to split the fact into 2 separate table - 1 where double counting is possible and 1 where it isn't

Answer (score 1):

You need many-to-many bridge table for this to handle multiple genres for the same movie. Your fact table will obviously have >1 movie. M2M table will show only dimensional relations between each movie and each genre.

Dimensions:

- Date (all years of all movies or dates in YYYYMMDD format as a key
  and additional columns like Year, Calendar Date MM/DD/YYYY etc. with
  key Date_SK)
- Genre (just flat key-value list like 1 - Action, 2 - Sci-Fi, 3 -
  Drama etc.)

Bridge table (+ separate measure group for this!):

- Movies_Genres (Movie_SK, Genre_SK). It will contain two rows for this movie. Row-1: 1,1; Row-2: 1,2

Fact table:

- Movies (Movie_SK, Title, Date_SK, Revenue)

Joins between all tables are:

- Date <-- Movies
- Movies_Genres <-- Movies
- Genre <-- Movies_Genres

On dimension usage tab you will join Movies fact table with Genre dimension by "Many-to-many relation" over Movies_Genres measure group that is already connected to Genre dimension.

This is the only way to avoid duplication. Server will go by each genre and in total you will see the same revenue as for each genre if one movie is selected.

Performance may be slow for bridge tables and dimensions with >1M rows each.